# how to use OneDrive File Picker JavaScript SDK v7.2?Authentication failed

Tags: javascript, azure, file, onedrive, picker

I am using `OneDrive File Picker JavaScript SDK v7.2` to develop. After the authorization is successful, after selecting the OneDrive file, this interface is `https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drives/27xxxxxx19/items/27xxxxxxxxEE19!106/? select=id,name,size,file,parentReference,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` returned to me `{code: "unauthenticated", message: "Authentication failed"}`, how can I solve this? Thank you.
some information below：

access permission：

```php
[
    'files.read',
    'files.read.all',
    'files.readwrite',
    'files.readwrite.all',
    'offline_access',
]
```

http request:

```
:authority: api.onedrive.com
:method: GET
:path: /v1.0/drives/277DxxxxxxxxEE19/items/277xxxxxxx1CEE19!106/?select=id,name,size,file,parentReference,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,zh-TW;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7
application: 0xe53186a8-5d36-4bf2-b7b7-e14a97fbe152
authorization: bearer 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
origin: http://localhost:7777
referer: http://localhost:7777/one-drive/index
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36
x-requeststats: SDK-Version=js-v7.2
```

http response:

```
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:7777
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Range, ETag, Location, Preference-Applied, X-Resource-ID, X-ClientErrorCode, MS-CV
date: Fri, 14 Aug 2020 06:14:37 GMT
ms-cv: 4S0AEzO9PUSKOPot44sYiA.0
p3p: CP="BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo"
status: 401
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
www-authenticate: Bearer realm="OneDriveAPI", error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid auth token"
x-asmversion: UNKNOWN; 19.523.807.2004
x-content-encoding-over-network: gzip
x-msedge-ref: Ref A: 1851F564465D4391AC3B6273785F2327 Ref B: HKBEDGE0208 Ref C: 2020-08-14T06:14:37Z
x-msnserver: SN3PPF7A19390B2
x-qosstats: {"ApiId":0,"ResultType":2,"SourcePropertyId":0,"TargetPropertyId":42}
x-throwsite: 4f37.717b
```

Comment: Since you are testing from localhost, is localhost added to your Microsoft Application Registration Portal App ID as a valid URL?

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I use the Azure platform. I added `http://localhost:7777/one-drive/index` to the redirectUrl when registering the app, but did not add the local url to the **Microsoft Application Registration Portal App ID** you mentioned , I can't find this place, can you help me with the following? thank you very much.

Comment: I do not use this functionality but according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/js-v72/?view=odsp-graph-online you need https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/